# Insulating value

Tags: vacuum, thermal-insulation

The level of vacuum (rough, high, etc) in a vacuum insulating panel determines its insulating value (typically measured in U or R value). Does the VOLUME matter? That is, for the same level of vacuum in an vacuum insulating panel with a thickness of 1 inch, would the performance be altered by being 2 inches thick?

Comment: Thickness of insulation always matters for conduction (and convection) in terms of energy; the vacuum is not perfect and so thickness will matter  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-value_(insulation)#Thickness. Volume is a different matter because more area tends to have the opposite effect of more thickness- bigger houses have more surface area.

Answer (score 0):

No, the goal is remove any conduction between the wall of the panel and any fluid within. This way the only means of transmission is radiation. I would like to argue however that having a greater volume in an imperfect vacuum would make things worse as there is more stuff in the gap to transmit heat, but I think it would be negligible.